# The square of Abs of a complex number

Tags: functions, complex, vector-calculus, built-in-symbols, arithmetic

We all know that

```
4^2 + 22^2 = 500
```

Is there a natural way to generates `500` from the complex number `4 + 22I` ?

Two examples :

ex1)
`Abs[4 + 22I]^2` generates `500`, but first `Abs[4 + 22I]` becomes `(Sqrt[500])^2`, then `(10 Sqrt[5])^2`, then `100*5`, then `500`. It generated 500 but did some unnecessary works.

```
Trace[Norm[4 + 22 I]^2]
```

{{{{{I,I},22 I,22 I},4+22 I,4+22 I},Norm[4+22 I],10 Sqrt[5]},(10 Sqrt[5])^2,100 5,500}

ex2)
`(Re[#]^2+Im[#]^2)&[4 + 22I]` generates `500` but I believe there should be a built-in function.

The problem was about performance and naturality of the program.

Thanks to MichaelE2, there is a built-in function Internal`AbsSquare[] with good performance.

The below screenshot will help you understand everything.

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

[image: This will help]

Comment: `Norm[4 + 22 I]^2` ?

Comment: `(4 + 22 I)*Conjugate[4 + 22 I]` or `#*Conjugate[#] &[(4 + 22 I)]`?

Comment: Trace[Norm[4 + 22 I]^2] helps to understand what CPU had done. I guess (Re[#]^2+Im[#]^2)& or #*Conjugate[#] & are the best..

Comment: `|z|^2 = z z*` where `z*` is the complex conjugate of `z` (more commonly shown with an overbar but I don't know how to do LaTeX on MSE.

Comment: I'm inferring from the way you ask the question that you'd like to be able to manipulate a complex number by sort of lifting it out of the complex context, just treating it as a 2D vector of reals. You can do this "lifting" with ReIm. ReIm[4+22I] gives {4,22}. Continuing, ReIm[4 + 22 I]^2 gives {16,484}. And continuing further, ReIm[4 + 22 I]^2 // Total gives 500. But without knowing your context, I don't know why this would be any better than using Norm or any of the other previous suggestions.

Comment: Because of the performance. In my computer, Do[Norm[(5790570927 + 49802948104 I)]^2, 10000] takes 2.375 seconds while Do[# Conjugate[#] & (5790570927 + 49802948104 I), 10000] takes 0.015 seconds.

Comment: There is an answer but I can't post it: `Internal`AbsSquare[]` is faster than `# Conjugate[#] &` on my machine (mmv). (Did you mean `Do[# Conjugate[#] & [5790570927 + 49802948104 I], 10000]`, because the code in your comment has a mistake?)

Comment: Thank you, Michael E2, that was exactly what I wanted. The function Internal`AbsSquare[ ] is built-in and 2 times faster then # Conjugate[#]& or Re[#]^2+Im[#]^2&.

Comment: One suggestion would be to edit your question to include your problem of performance. If you do this then I see a good reason for the question to be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Using `AbsoluteTiming` is better than `Timing`, as for example, if the kernel splits the work among the 8 cores of computer, you may well get an answer that is 8 times longer than the time spent in real life (depending on OS details).

My first suggestion would have been `Conjugate[#]#&`.  On my machine it is within 50% of `` Internal`AbsSquare ``.  Whether the speed difference justifies using an undocumented function is a question for you and whether calculating the squared modulus is really the critical point in your application.

```
Do[(# Conjugate[#] &)[(5790570927 + 49802948104 I)], 10000] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.118674, Null}*)

Do[Internal`AbsSquare[(5790570927 + 49802948104 I)], 10000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.07619, Null} *)
```